Symfony UX and Dropzone : How to download files
I would like to use Symfony UX and the Dropzone component in my project to allow image downloading.
Everything seems to work fine. However, I can't get the files in my controller to process and upload them.
How can I retrieve the files from my controller? Thanks
I tried to retrieve the files via $_FILES or via the request. But it doesn't contain anything.
I used a FormType that I inject into my controller to display dropzone. All with Symfony UX. Below is my controller displaying my form and the FormType in question.
FormType :
    <?php
    
    namespace App\Form;
    
    use App\Entity\Ad;
    use App\Entity\Package;
    use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CheckboxType;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\IntegerType;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\NumberType;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
    use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
    use Symfony\UX\Dropzone\Form\DropzoneType;
    
    class PackageFormType extends AbstractType
    {
        public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
        {
            $builder
                ->add('quantity', IntegerType::class, [
                    'label' => 'Quantité',
                ])
                ->add('name', TextType::class, [
                    'label' => "Nom de l'objet",
                    'attr' => [
                        'placeholder' => "Canapé, table de salle à manger, Cartons de livres…"
                    ]
                ])
                ->add('length', NumberType::class, [
                    'label' => 'Longueur (cm)',
                ])
                ->add('width', NumberType::class, [
                    'label' => 'Largeur (cm)'
                ])
                ->add('height', NumberType::class, [
                    'label' => 'Hauteur (cm)'
                ])
                ->add('file', DropzoneType::class, [
                    'multiple' => true,
                    'mapped' => false
                ])
                ->add('ecofriendly', CheckboxType::class, [
                    'label' => false,
                    'required' => false
                ])
            ;
        }
    
        public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
        {
            $resolver->setDefaults([
                'data_class' => Package::class,
            ]);
        }
    }

My Controller :
#[Route('/envoyer-un-colis', name: 'app_ad')]
    public function index(Request $request): Response
    {
        $ad = new Ad;
        $package = new Package;
        $package->setQuantity(1);
        $ad->getPackages()->add($package);

        $form = $this->createForm(AdFormType::class, $ad);
    
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        (HERE I WOULD LIKE TO CHECK $_FILES BUT EMPTY)
            if ($this->getUser()) {
                foreach($ad->getPackages() as $package) {
                    $package->setAd($ad);
                }
                $ad->setCreatedAt(new \DateTime());
                $ad->setUser($this->getUser());
                $this->em->persist($ad);
                $this->em->flush();
                return $this->redirectToRoute('app_bravo');
            } else {
                return $this->redirectToRoute('app_login');
            }
        }
        
        return $this->render('ad/index.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form,
        ]);
    }


Welcome to SO. You need to provide more information in order for anyone to help you. Did you implement a Form in order to use the drop zone? Did you use a DTO or Entity as the data for the form? If so, your file will be there. But again, I'm just guessing since you didn't share any code.

Hi @craigh
Thank you for your comment.
I've updated my post with the code

What does $ad->getFile() do? (or however you wrote your getter)

https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/upload_file.html
